# How to diplay a image popup when clicking on it in richtextblock: Windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

How can I implement with C#, so that each time I click on a image, it will be displayed in a popup? 
http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8403/8641588811_a87169fe58_b.jpg

```
RichTextBlock richText = d as RichTextBlock;
string xaml = HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml(xhtml, true);
RichTextBlock newRichText = (RichTextBlock)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
richText.Blocks.Clear();
for (int i = newRichText.Blocks.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Block b = newRichText.Blocks[i];
    newRichText.Blocks.RemoveAt(i);
    richText.Blocks.Insert(0, b);
 }
```

xaml content:

```
<RichTextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
               xmlns:control="using:TinTuc.Controls">
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Nếu em yêu một chàng trai Sư TửEm sẽ có một người mạnh mẽ, quyết đoán, đầy lòng kiêu hãnh và tự trọng ở bên.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Mang trong mình thuộc tính lửa, sự nhiệt tình, nhiệt huyết của Sư Tử luôn rất lớn nhưng những người thuộc cung hoàng đạo này cũng dễ dàng nổi giận. Nếu em yêu một chàng trai Sư Tử, sẽ ra sao?</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Em sẽ có bờ vai vững chắc để dựa những lúc mỏi mệt. Anh biết những bận rộn, những lo toan, cố gắng thường ngày sẽ khiến em cần một người ở bên cạnh, thậm chí chẳng nói gì cả, chỉ cần là nơi cho em dựa vào để quên những khó khăn, nhọc nhằn trước mắt. Với anh, thế là đủ rồi.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Có lúc anh sẽ làm em tổn thương vì những lần nóng giận. Nhưng Sư Tử có trí nhớ của cá, chỉ một chốc thôi là quên hết mọi bực bội trong lòng. Nên những lần anh sai như vậy, mong em hãy góp ý nhỏ nhẹ, đừng giận anh mà bỏ đi.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <ImageLoader xmlns="using:TinTuc.Controls" 
                         Source="http://img2.news.zing.vn/2013/04/12/4-15.jpg" 
                         Stretch="Uniform">
                <ImageLoader.LoadingContent>
                    <StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                                Width="420" 
                                MinHeight="250">
                        <ProgressRing VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                      IsActive="True" 
                                      Width="30" 
                                      Height="30" 
                                      Margin="10,100,10,30" 
                                      Foreground="Red"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ImageLoader.LoadingContent>
            </ImageLoader>
        </InlineUIContainer> Sư Tử luôn nhiệt tình nhưng rất dễ nổi giận.
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Em sẽ có một người mạnh mẽ, quyết đoán, đầy lòng kiêu hãnh và tự trọng ở bên. Những lúc em cần lời khuyên, khi con đường em đi đầy gai nhọn, lúc em vấp ngã cần người nâng dậy, anh sẽ không chỉ là người yêu, mà còn là người anh trai, là người bạn đồng hành để cùng em chia sẻ.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Em sẽ nhận được những sự chăm sóc, sự quan tâm ân cần từ một trái tim ấm áp. Nhưng đôi khi, em sẽ cảm thấy ngạt thở vì sự quan tâm thái quá ấy. Chỉ là anh luôn muốn mang lại mọi điều tốt đẹp nhất cho em mà thôi, đừng bực mình, đừng khó chịu với anh, em nhé!</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Em sẽ không được nghe những lời có cánh, sẽ có ít phút giây lãng mạn, ngọt ngào như em mong đợi, anh chỉ có một vòng ôm siết chặt, chỉ có một cái nắm tay ấm áp, chỉ có một đáy lòng thành thật mà đôi khi ngốc nghếch quá chừng thôi…</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Nếu em yêu một chàng trai Sư Tử, hãy dành tình yêu cho mình anh thôi. Sư Tử không bao giờ chấp nhận sự phản bội và những điều dối trá, nên đừng quay lưng giấu diếm anh điều gì dẫu chỉ một lần.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Đôi lúc em sẽ phải yêu chàng trai trẻ con và vô cùng ngang bướng. Hãy làm người lớn bao dung, nhưng nhớ đừng chiều quá, anh hư.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Nếu em yêu một chàng trai Sư Tử, em sẽ có tình yêu của một trái tim chân thành. Tuy có thể anh sẽ giả vờ lạnh lùng, đôi lúc vô tâm, nhưng thực tình anh luôn muốn gần bên em hơn nữa.</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Tưởng rằng oai hùng lắm, nhưng khi yêu em, Sư Tử chỉ như chú mèo nhỏ ngoan hiền. Và nếu em “lỡ” yêu phải một chàng trai Sư Tử, ở nơi đó, em sẽ thấy bình yên…</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">Theo Tiin</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight"/>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your effort first.. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: not constructive. should be supported with code.